# Is it smart to encrypt data with SHA256 using counter mode?

Tags: c++, c, qt, encryption, sha256

I have to encrypt users vpn passwords for a project. They are only stored at the local machine but i want to avoid plain text passwords on the hard drive. 
I re-salt and hash the users master-password to encrypt the vpn-passwords using XTEA in counter mode... 
Then i thought it's also possible to encrypt the vpn-passwords using sha256 in a sort of counter mode.

pseudo c code:

```
    string masterpasswd, txtdata;
    uint32_t data[] = unicode(txtdata);
    uint32_t key[8] = sha256(masterpasswd+salt);
    for(int i=0;i<data_size;i++) {
      encrypted[i] = data[i] ^ key[i];
      key=sha256(key+i);
    }
```

I don' want to use openssl because i am lazy ;)
Is this a smart solution?

Comment: Lazy people are usually good programmers. Good luck! ;)

Comment: SHA is a hash algorithm not a method of encryption.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious: I know, but i want to morph it into a encryption method. I asked because i'm not sure about the safety of this code.

Comment: You can't do that. If you need encryption use encryption. If you need a hash use a hash.

Comment: Professionally done production-grade encryption has issues every so often (there's a reason for OpenSSL versions going up to 1.0.0l and 1.0.1f). Homebaked encryption is universally, invariably fundamentally broken. It's much harder than you think it is. Devil is in the details. Those details break the bank.

Answer (score 3):

No - what happens when your data is larger than your key, for the users whose password is "correct horse battery staple"?

Either

- your code breaks because it tries to go for the 9th byte of an 8 byte key

or

- your actual implementation (rather than your pseudo-code) ends up wrapping around to byte 0 of the key again, i.e. ECB mode, which is the one mode you should never ever use (see [Adobe](http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/11/04/anatomy-of-a-password-disaster-adobes-giant-sized-cryptographic-blunder/)), since "passwordpassword" would then result in the same encrypted output twice, which is a huge hint.

More seriously, don't do this.  You should use PBKDF2 (for OpenSSL, that's PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC() with EVP_sha512() as the hash function - you'll need evp.h and sha.h)  to derive an encryption key of the required size from your master password and salt, and then use, say, OpenSSL to actually do the encryption using something other than ecb mode.

Comment: You're on a mission, and I approve of your mission. It's a good mission to be on, and as far as missions go, it's never-ending. Good luck :)

Answer (score -1):

You can be even more lazy and use existing class for Qt [Simple Crypt](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Simple_encryption) :)

Comment: Using home-baked "encryption" is always bad idea. Since linking Qt with openssl is trivial, even if you want a statically linked windows executable, I really see no reason for home-baked solutions at all. Basically, if it's for encryption and not a popular library that has been looked at by people who know what they are doing, it's safest to assume that it's broken.

Comment: @KubaOber if u have read the article: "Strong cryptography is obviously the best solution [...] it may just be overkill for the situation."